# Copying table data into javascript json object within page

Tags: javascript, d3.js, html-table

I have a page with mainly an html table having several columns.

Two of which are longitude and latitude which can be referenced by `#tablename tr td:nth-child(9)` and 10.

After the page is loaded I want to copy every row for the two columns into a javascript json object.

I plan to use the json to populate a dynamically generated graph (d3 geo).

The main aim to avoid embedding a duplicate copy of the data in json form within the page.

Note that the table and javascript code will be on the same page and the table data will never be modified.

Any suggestions or libraries to easily achieve this?

Comment: If the table is being generated programmatically, is it not easier to tap into the source of the table? Or is that not possible due to some other restrictions? Also could you share a sample of the table either as a screenshot or as markdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [JQuery](https://code.jquery.com/) plugin for [Table To  JSON](https://plugins.jquery.com/tabletojson/) like so:

```js
let data = $(`#myTable`).tableToJSON();
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/table-to-json@1.0.0/lib/jquery.tabletojson.min.js" 
        integrity="sha256-H8xrCe0tZFi/C2CgxkmiGksqVaxhW0PFcUKZJZo1yNU=" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Catalog</th>
      <th>HIP</th>
      <th>Proxy</th>
      <th>RAhms</th>
      <th>DEdms</th>
      <th>Vmag</th>
      <th>VarFlag</th>
      <th>r_Vmag</th>
      <th>RAdeg</th>
      <th>DEdeg</th>
      <th>Plx</th>
      <th>pmRA</th>
      <th>pmDE</th>
      <th>e_RAdeg</th>
      <th>e_DEdeg</th>
      <th>e_Plx</th>
      <th>e_pmRA</th>
      <th>e_pmDE</th>
      <th>DE:RA</th>
      <th>BTmag</th>
      <th>e_BTmag</th>
      <th>VTmag</th>
      <th>e_VTmag</th>
      <th>m_BTmag</th>
      <th>B-V</th>
      <th>e_B-V</th>
      <th>r_B-V</th>
      <th>V-I</th>
      <th>e_V-I</th>
      <th>r_V-I</th>
      <th>Hpmag</th>
      <th>e_Hpmag</th>
      <th>Hpscat</th>
      <th>o_Hpmag</th>
      <th>m_Hpmag</th>
      <th>Hpmax</th>
      <th>HPmin</th>
      <th>Period</th>
      <th>HvarType</th>
      <th>Ncomp</th>
      <th>MultFlag</th>
      <th>Qual</th>
      <th>m_HIP</th>
      <th>theta</th>
      <th>rho</th>
      <th>Survey</th>
      <th>Chart</th>
      <th>HD</th>
      <th>CoD</th>
      <th>(V-I)red</th>
      <th>SpType</th>
      <th>r_SpType</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="85344">
      <td> H </td>
      <td> <a target="_blank" href="http://news.sky-map.org/starview?object_type=1&amp;object_id=343839">85344</a> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> 17 26 23.25 </td>
      <td> +22 06 35.5 </td>
      <td> 8.81 </td>
      <td> 2 </td>
      <td> H </td>
      <td> 261.59688825 </td>
      <td> +22.10985186 </td>
      <td> 3.28 </td>
      <td> 6.04 </td>
      <td> -21.15 </td>
      <td> 0.73 </td>
      <td> 0.95 </td>
      <td> 1.22 </td>
      <td> 1.14 </td>
      <td> 1.57 </td>
      <td> -0.26 </td>
      <td> 10.969 </td>
      <td> 0.042 </td>
      <td> 9.002 </td>
      <td> 0.014 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> 1.667 </td>
      <td> 0.036 </td>
      <td> T </td>
      <td> 1.99 </td>
      <td> 0.09 </td>
      <td> O </td>
      <td> 8.8883 </td>
      <td> 0.0035 </td>
      <td> 0.037 </td>
      <td> 153 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> 8.84 </td>
      <td> 8.95 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> U </td>
      <td> 1 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> 1.94 </td>
      <td> M1 </td>
      <td> S </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="85345">
      <td> H </td>
      <td> <a target="_blank" href="http://news.sky-map.org/starview?object_type=1&amp;object_id=1104384">85345</a> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> 17 26 24.05 </td>
      <td> +65 14 10.7 </td>
      <td> 8.72 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> H </td>
      <td> 261.60020844 </td>
      <td> +65.23630285 </td>
      <td> 1.87 </td>
      <td> -6.50 </td>
      <td> 6.18 </td>
      <td> 0.59 </td>
      <td> 0.70 </td>
      <td> 0.69 </td>
      <td> 0.52 </td>
      <td> 0.79 </td>
      <td> -0.10 </td>
      <td> 9.982 </td>
      <td> 0.022 </td>
      <td> 8.820 </td>
      <td> 0.014 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> 0.997 </td>
      <td> 0.020 </td>
      <td> T </td>
      <td> 0.98 </td>
      <td> 0.02 </td>
      <td> L </td>
      <td> 8.8854 </td>
      <td> 0.0015 </td>
      <td> 0.013 </td>
      <td> 91 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> 8.86 </td>
      <td> 8.91 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> C </td>
      <td> 1 </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> 0.95 </td>
      <td> G0 </td>
      <td> S </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```